# Adding try/except to imported library code I have no access to?

Tags: python, websocket, graphql

I'm subscribing to a GraphQL endpoint, using the Python library [py-graphql-client](https://github.com/ecthiender/py-graphql-client). This uses standard Python `websocket`. After a day or so, I get the following error:

```
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 81, in recv
    bytes_ = sock.recv(bufsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1227, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1102, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

In my own code I would add a try/except clause to capture and process the error, but this is from the standard library.
How would I go and protect against this error?

Comment: Put the `try/except` in your code that calls the library function.

Comment: Do you know if the server is sending a Keep Alive signal that you can acknowledge? Sometimes this error occurs because the server boots connections after a certain duration.

Comment: The server is specifically setup to be an endpoint for GraphQL with subscriptions over web socket. I can’t verify if the server is sending a keep alive signal. It does work for 24+ hours or so and then it doesn’t (last failure was 2 sec after receiving last message). 

Ideally I would build something that restarts the web socket connection when it fails, but right now, the place where it fails doesn’t inspire much confidence that that is a viable path.